# Amateur with this array algorithms in pseudocode, just started learning so I'm really unsure

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Was recently taught on array and I'm really lost, would love some advice!

The algorithm AddMul6(A, n) is shown below. What is the value returned by AddMul6([3, 5, 7, 9], 4)?

```
AddMul6(A, n) {

sum = A[0]

for i = (1 to (n-1))   {

sum = sum + i

return sum

}

}
```

And just 1 more question as well similar in nature

The algorithm CalVal1(x) is shown below, what is the value returned by CalVal1(5)?

```
CalVal1(x) {

If  (x ≥ 5) 

x = x +10

else

x = x + 100

return x

}
```

Comment: Where do these questions come from?

Comment: In the first case, it would be more logical to have `sum = sum + A[i]` instead of `sum = sum + i`

Comment: @Damien: I suspect that the point is to see if the (student? interviewee? other?) is actually reading the code. It also helps to compare the first and second examples to see how this pseudo-language is constructed. When you do that these questions have "interview question" written all over them. :-)

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica OK. So, do I pass the exam? :)

Comment: @Damien: that's not up to me to determine. Personally, I would update the questions with different indentation and brace positioning to allow the structure of the code to be more easily interpreted but obviously the author of these questions and I differ on what we want to get out of questions like this. I figure that an interviewee is already in a stressful situation and compounding that situational stress with easy-to-misinterpret pseudocode is unrealistic. Anyways, I'd rather give them a FizzBuzz-like program to write. But, y'know, some people just like messing with other people...

Comment: @Aurelias Pay attention that these programmes become much easier to understand with a good identation. Were you given these codes with such a bad identation?